# Create header of a dataframe from the first row in the data frame

Tags: r, indexing

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame(a=c("f", 2, 3), b=c("g", 3, 7), c=c("h", 2, 4))
```

and I would like to create column names from the first row. MY guess was:

```
names(a) <- a[1,]
```

which gives:

```
names(a)
[1] "3" "3" "3"
```

I did not fully get what is happening. Can anyone explain and help me on how to do it the right way?

Comment: not sure why.. but you can just wrap `a[1, ]` in `unlist()`

Comment: Why do you have this data.frame? Looks like a problem that should be solved during data import/creation.

Comment: @Roland I import a csv containing factors and numerical data. therefore I can't use a matrix...if this is what you mean.

Comment: If you import a CSV, `read.csv` should recognize the column headers.

Comment: yes. but the first line does not contain the actual header but metadata-blabla. Bad secondary data I have to clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of a are factors with each column having different levels. R casts them to ints. Since, for each column the letter appears last alphanumerically it gets assigned the value 3.

Try

```
names(a) = as.character(unlist(a[1,]))
names(a)
```

Comment: What is the `as.character` doing in this answer?

Comment: Nothing! Works without it entirely!

Comment: It seems that `names()` does the conversion of factor to character itself

Comment: ... at which point, unfortunately, this answer is the same as Jilber's, posted a couple of minutes before you, and as the answer that was posted by rawr at one point in the comments... Oh well....

Comment: ok you saved my life...but what was happening here? I'm cleaning up a large Excel file and this example isn't helping me..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> colnames(a) <- unlist(a[1,])
> a
  f g h
1 f g h
2 2 3 2
3 3 7 4
```

Comment: I don't think `droplevels` is required here, is it?

Comment: You are right @AnandaMahto, It's 8:20am, it's too early to think about R, need a coffee and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: or 8PM for folk like me, perhaps too late to think about R :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
janitor::row_to_names(a,1)
```

janitor package gives the cleanest way to shift any data row up as column names.